# Using pagination with lots of similar HTML elements in the same file?

Tags: html, css, flask, pagination, jinja2

So I'm making a web app to run a small CTF that I will be hosting within my school, and I have developed a webpage that will load up the problems, my example right now lays out the problems in a long row

Here's how that's done:

```
    <body class="main-body">

        <div class="body">

            <section class="content">

                <div class="container-asdf"> <!-- This is a grid, assume that this particular element is repeated several times with changes -->
                    <div class="item-a">Test Problem</div>
                    <div class="item-b">Category: Test, Problem</div>
                    <div class="item-c"><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Button</button></div>
                </div>

             </section>
        </div>
    </body>
```

(Full disclosure that this HTML is likely pretty bad, just working with what I know)

the div with class "container-asdf" is automatically generated for the amount of problems, assume it works perfectly and it generates say 50 problems, I only want 10 of them to appear on the page at a time and I want to separate them using pagination, without having to make a ton of different HTML pages, how exactly could I do this? I don't need code, just some concepts and guides of how I could. My first thought process was to put it in invisible containers and make it appear as you select different numbers, thus why I asked how to use pagination

In summary: I have a lot of elements(in the same HTML file) appearing on the page at once, I want to limit this and split it into pages without having to make multiple HTML files, I am using Flask/Jinja to generate said HTML file, if that helps.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies but have you considered using the easyPaginate jQuery plugin for the pagination? An example and setup is available [here](https://st3ph.github.io/jquery.easyPaginate/).

Comment: Thank you! i will look into it when I work on my page again, anything is helpful!